# Unable to detect USB device

Tags: c++, qt, usb, qextserialport

Here is my code:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qdebug.h>

   MyClass::MyClass()
   {
       QList<QextPortInfo> ports = QextSerialEnumerator::getPorts();

       int counter=0;

       while(counter<ports.size())
       {
       QString portName = ports[counter].portName;
       QString productId= ports[counter].productID;
       QString physicalName = ports[counter].physName;
       QString vendorId = ports[counter].vendorID;
       QString friendName = ports[counter].friendName;


       string convertedPortName = portName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
       string convertedProductId = productId.toLocal8Bit().constData();
       string convertedPhysicalName = physicalName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
       string convertedVendorId = vendorId.toLocal8Bit().constData();
       string convertedFriendName = friendName.toLocal8Bit().constData();

       cout << "Port Name: " << convertedPortName << endl;
       cout << "Product ID:" << convertedProductId << endl;
       cout << "Physical Name: " << convertedPhysicalName << endl;
       cout << "Vendor Id: " << convertedVendorId << endl;
       cout << "Friend Name: " << convertedFriendName << endl;
       cout << endl;
       counter++;

       }
   }
```

I have connected "Dreamcheeky Thunder Missile Launcher" USB toy, but I am unable to get it's Vendor ID or product ID or atleast anything related to it! See the following image

[image]

But using USBDView software, I can get all the details. See the following image

[image]

What is matter with My code? Or if it is simply not suitable?

Comment: QExtSerial is for serial ports, so I assume it lists serial devices (some of the emulated), not USB. I'd try with libusb.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I installed it, and it messed everything. The Toy's software also stopped working. Anyway, if I start a new thread seeking for install help, do you mind giving me step by step instructions?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence: have you tried QtSerialPort?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Just running the installer for the toy and checking what it comes up with, it doesn't describe any API or documentation for accessing it as a serial port.</strike>

If you used some sort of monitoring program on their program you could maybe reverse engineer how it commands the device.

It may be easier just to interface with their UI directly.  Using a program like AHK or calling SendInput() to coordinates relative to the upper left corner of their UI, you could command the directions of the device.

[image: Missile Launcher UI]

EDIT: More links related to this:
Because the USB device doesn't get listed as a COM# (how serial port shows up), and it is a HID device, you need a library that can talk to that.  Here are some links that should help you get there:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41075-USB-HID-connect-on-QT

http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/

https://github.com/iia/Qt_libusb

It also looks like the guys at Robo Realm have done it already:

http://www.roborealm.com/help/DC_Missile.php

http://www.roborealm.com/help/USB_HID.php

http://www.roborealm.com/tutorial/usb_missile_launcher/slide010.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, this device can be programmed. They have a documentation which describes the signals we need to send

Comment: Thats for the OIC launcher, but they confirmed the stuff are same except the missing camera. I managed to find it is true by USB monitoring software